# Updating nested object in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, nested

PROBLEM: I am having an issue in updating a nested object in Elastic Search using script.
I want to update some portion of my document so that I can achieve my desired result.

Below are sample code.

1. I have below product mapping

```
  PUT products
    {
      "mappings": {
          "properties": {
            "category": {
              "type": "nested",
              "properties": {
                "category_code": {
                 "type":  "keyword"
                  },
                 "zaiko": {
                  "type": "integer"
                 },
                 "categories": {
                   "type": "object",
                   "properties": {
                     "category_cd": {
                       "type": "text"
                     },
                     "zaiko": {
                       "type": "integer"
                     }
                   }
                 }
                }
              }
            }
        }
    }
```

2. Data inserted in above mapping like below

   ```
   POST /products/_doc/1
    {
     "category": [{
       "category_code": "201",
       "ziko": 100,
       "categories": {
         "category_code": "20101",
         "zaiko": 50
       }
     }]
   }

   POST /products/_doc/2
   {
   "category": [{
    "category_code": "201",
    "ziko": 100,
    "categories": {
     "category_code": "20102",
     "zaiko": 60
   }
   }]}
   ```
3. I want to update nested categories object (Zaiko Field) and using below script for it

   ```
   POST /products/_update_by_query
    {
      "script": {
      "lang": "painless",
      "source": """
       for (int i=0; i < ctx._source.category.length; i++) { 
        if(ctx._source.category[i].categories.category_code == "20101"){
          ctx._source.category[i].categories.zaiko = params.zaiko;
        }
      } 
      """,
      "params": {
        "zaiko": 10
      }
    },
    "query": {
     "nested": {
      "path": "category",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match": {
                "category.categories.category_cd": "20101"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
     }
    }
   }
   ```

In response to this query nested categories, zaiko field is not updated.
Can anyone suggest me, How can we update the nested object in Elastic Search using Script?

Answer (score 1):

I seems trivial but how about changing the last `match` from

```
"category.categories.category_cd": "20101"
```

to

```
"category.categories.category_code": "20101"
```

I.e. `cd` --> `code`

Comment: thanks for your answer I made a typo mistake. I correct the match query as you suggest it working fine.